# Flutter app is not opening after firebase install

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have installed a firebase plugin in my app and copy the google-service.json file but when I run the app its not opening

I only have a single plugin which is  `cloud_firestore: ^0.13.7`

And my app level build.gradle file is

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.rotaryadyar"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

}
```

After installing firebase and google file its showing some error then I add this multidexEnabled then error is not showing but after app building its not opening

Comment: try `flutter run --verbose` if you'll get the error message

Comment: its also not showing any error last lines are this Waiting for observatory port to be available...
and when I simply run its just stopping on installing app

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried invalidating caches and restarting android studio I had that issue and after that my app was running or reduce to version 0.13.6

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the integration is not completed.

> Modify the android/build.gradle file and the android/app/build.gradle file to add the Google services plugin as described by the Firebase assistant. Ensure that your android/build.gradle file contains the maven.google.com as described here.

I personally recommend that you follow integration steps 1-3 of the firebase_messaging package, which are similar:

1. Using the Firebase Console add an Android app to your project: Follow the assistant, download the generated `google-services.json` file and place it inside `android/app`.
2. Add the classpath to the [project]/android/build.gradle file.

```
dependencies {
  // Example existing classpath
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
  // Add the google services classpath
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
}
```

3. Add the apply plugin to the [project]/android/app/build.gradle file.

```
// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

---

**PLEASE NOTE**: The integration explicitly says to put `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the end of the file. But you have it in the middle of the file. Maybe this is your mistake.